# Rails created_at on display if Today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, date

Is it possible to display the created_at date, only if that date matches today's date?

```
<%=h k.created_at %>
```

Is this possible? Or should it be done in the controller rather than the view?

Thanks,

Danny

I have the following in my environment.rb:

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => '%d/%m/%Y')
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a `helper`...

```
def created_at_for_view k
   k.created_at if k.created_at.to_date == Date.today
end
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking once that helpers in kases_helper.rb, I should be able to call it using <%=h k.created_at_for_view %> ?

Comment: You should call `created_at_for_view(k)`

Comment: That doesn't result in any errors - but doesnt display anything either. :(

Comment: It's creating the empty span so I presume it's just not finding anything to return. Could this be because I have altered the date format in the environment.rb? I have updated my question with my alterations.

Comment: Not sure. I edited my answer, added a `to_date`... I believe it may work now.