# Rails helper, show word not date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, date, helper

A follow on from this questions:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032598/rails-created-at-on-display-if-today
```

Is it possible to output the word TODAY rather than the date when using the following helper?

```
def created_today k
   k.created_at if k.created_at.to_date == Date.today
end

<%=h created_today(k) %>
```

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def created_today k 
   "Today" if k.created_at.to_date == Date.today 
end
```

Comment: Worked a treat, I didn't realise you could just replace the string with anything you like! Thanks...again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the date if it's not today:

```
def created_today k 
  if k.created_at.to_date == Date.today then 
    content_tag(:span, 'Today', :class => "highlight") 
  else 
    k.created_at.to_s(:long) 
  end
end
```

In your css, you describe how you want to 'highlight' it

Comment: Thats a nice idea, is it possible to give the two different styles? So if it was today I could style it to be highlighted?

Comment: Great, thats really brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def created_today k
  'TODAY' if k.created_at.to_date == Date.today
end

<%=h created_today(k) %>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, should I be able to put anything in place of DATE?

Currently, using your suggestion, I just get an empty span.

Comment: Thanks for helping Mark, it seems replacing puts 'TODAY' with just "TODAY" works a charm. Thanks again.